# Dynamically create hash from array of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, algorithm

I want to dynamically create a Hash without overwriting keys from an array of arrays. Each array has a string that contains the nested key that should be created. However, I am running into the issue where I am overwriting keys and thus only the last key is there

```
data = {}

values = [
  ["income:concessions",  0, "noi", "722300",  "purpose", "refinancing"],
  ["fees:fee-one", "0" ,"income:gross-income", "900000", "expenses:admin", "7500"],
  ["fees:fee-two", "0", "address:zip", "10019", "expenses:other", "0"]
]
```

What it should look like:

```
{ 
  "income" => {
    "concessions" => 0,
    "gross-income" => "900000"
    },
    "expenses" => {
      "admin" => "7500",
      "other" => "0"
    } 
  "noi" => "722300", 
  "purpose" => "refinancing", 
  "fees" => {
    "fee-one" => 0,
    "fee-two" => 0
    },

  "address" => {
    "zip" => "10019"
  }
}
```

This is the code that I currently, have how can I avoid overwriting keys when I merge?

```
values.each do |row|
  Hash[*row].each do |key, value|
    keys = key.split(':')

    if !data.dig(*keys)
      hh = keys.reverse.inject(value) { |a, n| { n => a } }
      a = data.merge!(hh)
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've provided can be modified to merge hashes on conflict instead of overwriting:

```
values.each do |row|
  Hash[*row].each do |key, value|
    keys = key.split(':')

    if !data.dig(*keys)
      hh = keys.reverse.inject(value) { |a, n| { n => a } }
      data.merge!(hh) { |_, old, new| old.merge(new) }
    end
  end
end
```

But this code only works for the two levels of nesting.

By the way, I noted `ruby-on-rails` tag on the question. There's `deep_merge` method that can fix the problem:

```
values.each do |row|
  Hash[*row].each do |key, value|
    keys = key.split(':')

    if !data.dig(*keys)
      hh = keys.reverse.inject(value) { |a, n| { n => a } }
      data.deep_merge!(hh)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
values.flatten.each_slice(2).with_object({}) do |(f,v),h|
  k,e = f.is_a?(String) ? f.split(':') : [f,nil]
  h[k] = e.nil? ? v : (h[k] || {}).merge(e=>v)
end 
  #=> {"income"=>{"concessions"=>0, "gross-income"=>"900000"},
  #    "noi"=>"722300",
  #    "purpose"=>"refinancing",
  #    "fees"=>{"fee-one"=>"0", "fee-two"=>"0"},
  #    "expenses"=>{"admin"=>"7500", "other"=>"0"},
  #    "address"=>{"zip"=>"10019"}}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
values = [
  ["income:concessions",  0, "noi", "722300",  "purpose", "refinancing"],
  ["fees:fee-one", "0" ,"income:gross-income", "900000", "expenses:admin", "7500"],
  ["fees:fee-two", "0", "address:zip", "10019", "expenses:other", "0"]
]

a = values.flatten
  #=> ["income:concessions", 0, "noi", "722300", "purpose", "refinancing",
  #    "fees:fee-one", "0", "income:gross-income", "900000", "expenses:admin", "7500",
  #    "fees:fee-two", "0", "address:zip", "10019", "expenses:other", "0"]
enum1 = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["income:concessions", 0, "noi", "722300",
  #    "purpose", "refinancing", "fees:fee-one", "0", "income:gross-income", "900000",
  #    "expenses:admin", "7500", "fees:fee-two", "0", "address:zip", "10019",
  # "expenses:other","0"]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see what values this enumerator will generate by converting it to an array.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["income:concessions", 0], ["noi", "722300"], ["purpose", "refinancing"],
  #    ["fees:fee-one", "0"], ["income:gross-income", "900000"],
  #    ["expenses:admin", "7500"], ["fees:fee-two", "0"],
  #    ["address:zip", "10019"], ["expenses:other", "0"]]
```

Continuing,

```
enum2 = enum1.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #     ["income:concessions", 0, "noi", "722300", "purpose", "refinancing",
  #      "fees:fee-one", "0", "income:gross-income", "900000", "expenses:admin", "7500",
  #      "fees:fee-two", "0", "address:zip", "10019", "expenses:other", "0"]
  #      :each_slice(2)>:with_object({})>
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[["income:concessions", 0], {}], [["noi", "722300"], {}],
  #    [["purpose", "refinancing"], {}], [["fees:fee-one", "0"], {}],
  #    [["income:gross-income", "900000"], {}], [["expenses:admin", "7500"], {}],
  #    [["fees:fee-two", "0"], {}], [["address:zip", "10019"], {}],
  #    [["expenses:other", "0"], {}]]
```

`enum2` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator* (though Ruby has no such concept). The hash being generated is initially empty, as shown, but will be filled in as additional elements are generated by `enum2`

The first value is generated by `enum2` and passed to the block, and the block values are assigned values by a process called [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
(f,v),h = enum2.next
  #=> [["income:concessions", 0], {}]
f #=> "income:concessions"
v #=> 0
h #=> {}
```

We now perform the block calculation.

```
f.is_a?(String)
  #=> true
k,e = f.is_a?(String) ? f.split(':') : [f,nil]
  #=> ["income", "concessions"]
e.nil?
  #=> false
h[k] = e.nil? ? v : (h[k] || {}).merge(e=>v)
  #=> {"concessions"=>0}
```

`h[k]` equals `nil` if `h` does not have a key `k`. In that case `(h[k] || {}) #=> {}`. If `h` does have a key `k` (and `h[k]` in not `nil`).`(h[k] || {}) #=> h[k]`.

A second value is now generated by `enum2` and passed to the block.

```
(f,v),h = enum2.next
  #=> [["noi", "722300"], {"income"=>{"concessions"=>0}}]
f #=> "noi"
v #=> "722300"
h #=> {"income"=>{"concessions"=>0}}
```

Notice that the hash, `h`, has been updated. Recall it will be returned by the block after all elements of `enum2` have been generated. We now perform the block calculation.

```
f.is_a?(String)
  #=> true
k,e = f.is_a?(String) ? f.split(':') : [f,nil]
  #=> ["noi"]
e #=> nil
e.nil?
  #=> true
h[k] = e.nil? ? v : (h[k] || {}).merge(e=>v)
  #=> "722300"
h #=> {"income"=>{"concessions"=>0}, "noi"=>"722300"}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`merge` overwrites a duplicate key by default.

`{ "income"=> { "concessions" => 0 } }.merge({ "income"=> { "gross-income" => "900000" } }` completely overwrites the original value of `"income"`. What you want is a recursive merge, where instead of just merging the top level hash you're merging the nested values when there's duplication.

`merge` takes a block where you can specify what to do in the event of duplication. From the documentation:

> **merge!(other_hash){|key, oldval, newval| block} → hsh**
>
> Adds the contents of other_hash to hsh. If no block is specified, entries with duplicate keys are overwritten with the values from other_hash, otherwise the value of each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key, its value in hsh and its value in other_hash

Using this you can define a simple `recursive_merge` in one line

```
def recursive_merge!(hash, other)
  hash.merge!(other) { |_key, old_val, new_val| recursive_merge!(old_val, new_val) }
end

values.each do |row|
  Hash[*row].each do |key, value|
    keys = key.split(':')
  
    if !data.dig(*keys)
      hh = keys.reverse.inject(value) { |a, n| { n => a } }
      a = recursive_merge!(data, hh)
    end
  end
end
```

A few more lines will give you a more robust solution, that will overwrite duplicate keys that are not hashes and even take a block just like `merge`

```
def recursive_merge!(hash, other, &block)
  hash.merge!(other) do |_key, old_val, new_val|
    if [old_val, new_val].all? { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) }
      recursive_merge!(old_val, new_val, &block)
    elsif block_given?
      block.call(_key, old_val, new_val)
    else
      new_val
    end
  end
end

h1 = { a: true, b: { c: [1, 2, 3] } }
h2 = { a: false,  b: { x: [3, 4, 5] } }
recursive_merge!(h1, h2) { |_k, o, _n| o } # => { a: true,  b: { c: [1, 2, 3],  x: [3, 4, 5] } }
```

**Note:** This method reproduces the results you would get from ActiveSupport's `Hash#deep_merge` if you're using Rails.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would handle this:

```
def new_h 
  Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = new_h}
end 

values.flatten.each_slice(2).each_with_object(new_h) do |(k,v),obj|
  keys =  k.is_a?(String) ? k.split(':') : [k]
  if keys.count > 1
    set_key = keys.pop
    obj.merge!(keys.inject(new_h) {|memo,k1| memo[k1] = new_h})
      .dig(*keys)
      .merge!({set_key => v})
  else
    obj[k] = v
  end
end
#=> {"income"=>{
       "concessions"=>0, 
       "gross-income"=>"900000"}, 
    "noi"=>"722300", 
    "purpose"=>"refinancing", 
    "fees"=>{
        "fee-one"=>"0", 
        "fee-two"=>"0"}, 
    "expenses"=>{
        "admin"=>"7500", 
        "other"=>"0"}, 
    "address"=>{
        "zip"=>"10019"}
    }
```

Explanation:

- Define a method (`new_h`) for setting up a new `Hash` with default `new_h` at any level (`Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = new_h}`)
- First flatten the `Array` (`values.flatten`)
- then group each 2 elements together as sudo key value pairs (`.each_slice(2)`)
- then iterate over the pairs using an accumulator where each new element added is defaulted to a `Hash` (`.each_with_object(new_h.call) do |(k,v),obj|`)
- split the sudo key on a colon (`keys =  k.is_a?(String) ? k.split(':') : [k]`)
- if there is a split then create the parent key(s) (`obj.merge!(keys.inject(new_h.call) {|memo,k1| memo[k1] = new_h.call})`)
- merge the last child key equal to the value (`obj.dig(*keys.merge!({set_key => v})`)
- other wise set the single key equal to the value (`obj[k] = v`)

This has infinite depth as long as the depth chain is not broken say `[["income:concessions:other",12],["income:concessions", 0]]` in this case the latter value will take precedence (**Note:** this applies to all the answers in one way or anther e.g. the accepted answer the former wins but a value is still lost dues to inaccurate data structure)

[repl.it Example](https://repl.it/KLET/7)